# ng-select inside ngx-datatable dropdown is not visible

Tags: angular6, ngx-datatable, angular-ngselect

(I reproduced my issue here: https://plnkr.co/QvEWjhJhbsghy1OD)

The `<ng-select>` drop down list of options is not displayed "over' the `<ngx-datatable>` row, it seems cut by the cell's height, making it pretty useless.

[image: cut off ng-select]

A regular `<select>` works fine though, I can see all options.

[image: working regular select]

How can I make the ng-select works as expected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use the `ng-select` attribute `appendTo="body"` as following:

```
<ng-select [searchable]="false" placeholder="-- choose --" appendTo="body">
   <ng-option>Option 1</ng-option>
   ...
```